# How to keep track of the sum of each of the three columns Java

Tags: java

My Question is how to get my program to add each column separately and then find the average afterwards. E.g. 33+42+11 /3 expressed in Java.

Hope that clarifies the question.

I have also linked the numbers and columns below

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Assignment
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
throws IOException
{
    
FileInputStream control = null;
Scanner scanner = null;  

if (args.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("file name expected");
    System.exit(0);
}
    
System.out.println("Opening file " + args[0]);
control = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
System.out.println("Opening of file " + args[0] + " successful");

scanner = new Scanner(control);

long sum = 0;
int count = 0;

if (!scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("No integers");
    System.exit(0);
}

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    long number = scanner.nextInt();
    sum += number; 
    count++;
}

long average = sum / count;

System.out.println(average);

control.close();

  }
}
```

This is the columns. Not too sure about how to make it start adding from 127 down to 10 and same for the other two columns

```
 127          33  22
 2147483647   42  59
 10           11  55
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your question is not clear. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

And also : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Keep an array of **three totals**, one for each column.  As you read the rows of numbers, add the first number to the first total, the second number to the second total, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think I was able to interpret the question.

Here is a working solution - note that you need to scan for one line at a time with one scanner, and then scan each of those lines to break it up into columns.  I then stored each of those sums and counts in an array, as you mentioned you wanted to use arrays.  However, I just made those arrays hold up to 10 counts, and didn't do any sizing checks on those - those types of issues seemed outside the scope of the original question.

https://repl.it/repls/TintedNarrowRectangle

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String fakeFileInput = " 127          33  22\n2147483647   42  59\n10  11     55";

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fakeFileInput);

    if (!scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("No integers");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    long[] sums = new long[10];
    int[] counts = new int[10];

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = scanner.nextLine();
      Scanner innerScan = new Scanner(line);
      int current = 0;
      while (innerScan.hasNextInt()) {
        int number = innerScan.nextInt();
        sums[current] += number; 
        counts[current] += 1;
        current++;
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) {
      System.out.println((1.0*sums[i])/counts[i] + " average for " + i + " column");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much i really appreciate this, apologies for the bad wording of the question

Answer (score 1):

I am just providing a 3 * 3 grid solution and my goal is to keep each column summation. My final output would be like {(127+2147483647+ 10), (33+42+11), (22+59+55)}

For that, you just need to maintain another array. For example, you will keep each column summation in sum[] array.

Since you have only 3 columns, you just need sum[] size 3.

```
int[] sum = new int[3]
```

After allocation, you can reset sum arrays each index value 0.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    sum[i]=0
  }
```

Now the only thing left is taking each row input value. Since you have only 3 columns in each row and totally of 3 raws. You can follow below code snippet.

```
 for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        sum[i] = sum[i] + number;
     }
 }
```

Now you can use sum[] array for your final result. Each sum[] index holds on each column summation.